# splitting list into sublist python

Tags: python

Here is a simple question from a python beginner:

I have a list with sublists: [[1,2,3],['a','b','c']]

I want [1,2,3],['a','b','c']

I tried:

```
M = [[1,2,3],['a','b','c']]
for item in M:
    print(item)

[1,2,3]

['a','b','c']
```

But I don't want to use print, and I need to nest the result [1,2,3],['a','b','c'] into another loop.

I tried searching the site for similar question but can't seem to find an answer that I can follow. Could you guys help me? Thanks!

Comment: You need to iterate through first list elements and then through second, right?

Comment: Do you want the answer to be like this.? `['1' '2' '3' 'a' 'b' 'c']`

Comment: You've already got `for item in M`, so what's the problem?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you want to do with the lists. You already have the data. Going from `[[1,2,3],['a','b','c']]` to `[1,2,3],['a','b','c']` is not a very meaningful change.

Comment: I want to create combinations of corresponding indices of lists. For example, I have M = [[1,2,3],['a','b','c']], and I want to have [ '1a' , '2b' , '3c']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticing your comment I have adjusted my answer with my attempt to deliver what you wanted. There are two options, option 1 with the dictionary will work with varying lengths of sublists

```
from collections import defaultdict

M = [[1,2,3],['a','b','c']]
d = defaultdict(list)
for sublist in M:
    for i,e in enumerate(sublist):
        d[i].append(e)
d = ["".join(str(e) for e in d[i]) for i in range(len(d))]
print (d)

#bonus alternative solution using zip()
d2 = ["".join(str(e) for e in tuple_) for tuple_ in zip(*M)]
print (d2)
```

Both print:

```
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Comment: Thank you so much your solutions work perfectly! Very easy to understand, too!

Comment: @Blue if my answer solves your problem don't forget to accept it :d it means I get points for my work :P